# How make two different divs the same height without javascript

Tags: html, css

I have a table with this structure

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>
                some data 
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>
                other data
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I would like to make the two divs the same height and the height will be equal to the higher one 
If there is any idea how to do this with out javascript like find some way or another to inclose the two divs in div container it would be appreciated

Comment: `table td div { height: 200px; }` ?

Answer (score 5):

The only way to do this without Javascript is to set the height of each `div` to 100%...

**However...** This means nothing, as the question then becomes, 100% of what?

As such, you need to add a **fixed height** to a shared parent in order for this to be calculable. The trick is to then give the parent a tiny value for its height in order to force it to expand to fit its children's height, e.g. by giving say, `table` a `height:1px`

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/BpjK8/5/)

CSS

```
div {
    border:1px solid red;
    height:100%;
}
table {
    height:1px;
}
```

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>some data
                <br />some data
                <br />some data
                <br />
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>other data</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

C'mon.... go with FLEX!

It's pretty easy to use and works like a charm.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="grid">
        Text
    </div>
    <div class="grid">
        Text<br />
        lorem ipsum dolor sit<br />
        text text
    </div>
    <div class="grid">
        Text
    </div>
    <div class="grid">
        Text
    </div>
</div>

.container { display: flex; }
.container .grid { background-color: lime; margin-right: 5px; flex: 1; }
.container .grid:last-child { margin-right: 0; }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SchweizerSchoggi/s8pzayep/1/

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this using margin trick

```
td div {
   margin : auto;
}
```

Update: 
Okay I was wrong, but you can use this:

```
    <html>
<header>
<style>
    td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        width: 50%;
    }

</style>
</header>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>
                some data dasffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>
                other data
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sorry, I'm on work, jsfiddle is blocked(insane hah), will try to create quick example in a seck

Answer (score 0):

you can give the div a class name . So it would be like

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="table_div">
            some data 
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="table_div">
            other data
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

and on your css part you can do this.

```
.table_div{
height:100px;// or any height you prefer
}
```

Comment: From my understanding the div's height will be `auto` and depend upon the content in it..

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you need to have two table data the same width and the same height. If you want to do that for some background on tables. You dont need setting same height to that divs. For Example you can explore my code (The **height** of the divs are **different**)

**HTML**

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus aspernatur atque dolore ea impedit incidunt labore laboriosam libero nulla, obcaecati odio, quos rerum!</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur et maxime quis. Ab animi distinctio dolor ducimus eos excepturi facilis hic incidunt iste itaque iusto labore laudantium, natus, perspiciatis placeat rem temporibus ullam ut veniam vero. Accusamus autem consequatur, consequuntur delectus exercitationem id labore magnam porro, quo sed similique soluta unde ut velit voluptate. Soluta, veniam?</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

**CSS**

```
table td {
    width: 50%;
    background: #000;
    vertical-align: top;
}
table div {
    background: #000;
    color: #f00;
}
```

HERE [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BpjK8/9/)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your responses 
This workaround worked for me

> http://jsfiddle.net/cW9p2/

```
.containter {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
    <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>column1</th>
            <th>column2</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <div class="containter">
                    <div class="cell">
                        content 1
                    </div>
                    <div class="cell">
                        content 2
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="containter">
                    <div class="cell">
                        content 2
                    </div>
                    <div class="cell">
                        content 2

                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```